# locationManeger.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

Tags: swift3, locationmanager, xcode8

Hi all I am on a tutorial for maps but it is using Xcode 7 in the tutorial.

In the tutorial he uses this link but it has been stopped in the new version. 
Can anybody let me know the best way to duplicate this?

I have added NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in the plist.

```
func locationAuthStatus() {
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse {
        map.showsUserLocation = true
    }else {

        //cant get this to work in ios10
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

solved....

I realised that I had created a constant named locationManager but spelt it lacationManager instead, I couldn't work out why it was asking me to change it to LacationManager then I realised the spelling mistake.

all works fine now.